# Connecting Magento to Facebook store

Tags: magento2, facebook

For a couple of days I've spend many hours trying to connect Magento to my Facebook store. After following all the steps provided in the Magento manual I always keep getting the following notification:

Unable to connect, please activate your token.

> 1. Go to the Magento Admin panel and click on System tab.
> 2. In the "Integrations" menu select "Magento Social".
> 3. Next to the Magento social line, click activate.
> 4. Come back to this page and click Refresh

So, I've followed these steps and still it doesn't seem to work.

Another option the screen gives me is the following:

Still unable to connect? Insert the token manually

> 1. Next to the Magento social line, click Reactivate.
> 2. In the opened popup click Reactivate.
> 3. Copy the Consumer Key code line and paste it here, click Send.

However, when I enter the code manually the following message appears:

The customer key you've entered cannot be found, please check code.

I already contacted the Facebook Business customer support, but they tell me they can't help me with it, since it's an Magento issue.

Anyone who knows where it might go wrong? I've seen another topic on here with the same question, but there they only referred to the manual again. I'm 100% sure I followed all the steps, since I've tried it over 15 times and used different manuals.